# Problems with Excel handling of the month of March in German language

Tags: excel, date

For work I have to use an Excel version in German. Excel handles the month of March (März) in a strange/wrong way. The standard German abbreviation in the month's list is MRZ (if I fill a series of months I get JAN, FEB, MRZ, ...). Similarly, if I format a date, say 1st of March 2024, with `"DD-MMM-YYYY"` (or, more correctly in German, `"TT-MMM-JJJJ"`) I get `"01-Mrz-2024"`.

However, this get produces an error:

```
= DATEVALUE("1-Mrz-24")
```

.. while this is correct:

```
= DATEVALUE("1-Mär-24")
```

There is apparently a lack of internal coherency: sometimes I have to use MRZ and sometimes MÄR. This creates problems when I link a DATEVALUE formula to a date cell.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't recommend you to post it in german as SO is an english website, and require english questions

Comment: So as far as I understand, you have a cell value somewhere which says "Mrz" and you are linking to it and passing the result to DATEVALUE, which complains about wrong format. Is that correct?

Comment: I know that there might be other ways to achieve the same result, perhaps even with a string substitution, etc... , nevertheless this looks to me as an error in Excel.

Comment: When we dealt with months in 5 EU languages we used the numbers 1 - 12 and only put the text at the final step for the charts.

Comment: In my Excel, I want sometimes to format a date by simply showing the month in letters, so I might use a format like "MMM". This would yield MRZ. If I then want to use this in a DATEVALUE formula, I simply cannot without additional correction

Comment: You can. The stored value is numeric and the format is for display only. So omit DateValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Control Panel set the following:

`Region and Language` -> `Formats` -> `Format`

Set this to `German (Austria)`

Comment: Excellent, it works! With the Austrian setting is March indeed always "Mär" and not sometimes "Mär" and sometimes "Mrz". Thanks

Comment: Actually, bulding on your solution, I have found an even better trick: In the Austrian-German setting the month of January is also changed (Jän instead of Jan), so it will again create confusion. It is best to use the Italian-German setting where both January and March are coherently encoded as JAN and MÄR

Comment: Or may be German (Belgium) ... not so clear, the German (Italy) has worked for a moment and then it didn't work any more ... !